# Issue with non-printable char while exporting CSV data (Windows-1252) to hive

Tags: csv, hive, mapr, external-tables

I am trying to create a hive table on top of following CSV dataset using OpenCSVSerde

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("quoteChar"='\"', "separatorChar"=',')
```

but the hive table is losing the `£` sign, and showing the replacement character `�`.

```
FWID,GENDER,Ethnicity,AgeAtPeriodEnd,RC_UnitCost,QUANTITY,ElemTypeDesc
2100001,F,White,WEEK,"£2,027.07",3455,AA - Community Meals
2100011,F,White,YEAR,"£75.00,488776",AA - Community Meals
2100044,M,White,WEEK,"£5.40,39.0",123,Ld-ExtDc - Day
2100044,M,White,WEEK,£5.40,9856,FF - Community Meals
2100044,M,White,WEEK,£5.40,"789,193",FF - Community Meals
2100044,M,White,WEEK,£5.40,"876,241",FE - Community Meals
2100044,M,White,WEEK,£5.40,3888,"Community Meals,ExtDc - Day"
2100044,M,White,WEEK,£5.40,235,Ld-ExtDc - Day
2100044,M,White,WEEK,£5.40,8789,FE - Community Meals
2100044,M,White,WEEK,"£10.07,027.7",16478,FE - Community Meals
2100051,F,White,WEEK,£470.00,12375,RG - Community Meals
```

Also, I tried to create table using LazySimpleSerDe

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'escape.delim'='\"', 'field.delim'=',', 'line.delim'='\n', 'serialization.encoding'='windows-1252')
```

In this case, data is parsing correctly with the `£` sign but the alignment of values not working due to the missing `quotechar` as `\"`.

Please suggest the way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Open CSV file in Notepad++ and convert Encoding to UTF-8 and push
   the file to HDFS.
2. Create External Table with below properties.

```
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
      'field.delim'=',',
      'line.delim'='\n',
      'serialization.format'=',',
      'serialization.encoding'='UTF-8')
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
      'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1")
```